How do change text color of spinner when disabled?
I want to change text color after
binding.spnrRelationshipExistingBovineLoanApplicant.isEnabled = false

to black text color. when I disable it it gets grey.
<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnr_relationship_existing_bovine_loan_applicant"
                    style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/ic_down_arrow"
                    android:entries="@array/select"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

Tried to not use isEnabled because it makes my text color grey. I am expecting to disable that spinner without using isEnable = false . So that my text will reamin in black color only.

Use a selector:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>

state_enabled should respond to enabled events and you can use the colors you want (or both black in this case). Add the file to your res/color folder, and refer it on your textColor, or actually anything else that holds an android view state

i added this file and set android:textColor="@color/spinner_disable_enable_color" in respective spinner tag still its not working as i expect . Text is still grey.
